# Connecting to tensorflow serving from PHP

Tags: php, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

The connection between Tensorflow serving to PHP is quite immature. I could not find any relevant information online.

In theory it should be possible to compile the proto files to pb.php files, but it fails on proto files dependencies due to the fact that some of the proto files are located in tensorflow_serving/apis/ and others in tensorflow/core/framework/ . I tried every possible combination without success.

If you have any success/knowledge on connecting to tensorflow serving from PHP gRPC client, please post the details. Specifically how to compile the proto files and how to use pb.php files with protocol buffers runtime to actually connect to tensorflow server through gRPC

Alternatively, if you have successfully compiled the proto files please share them and how to use them.

Any information will help.  Thanks!